# Looking to achieve frame effect with shadows at corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

Where can I find PSD file or tutorial to create the effect of frame with shadow (see red arrow in image)

[image]

Comment: A package of shadows for photoshop: http://www.graphicsfuel.com/2011/04/content-box-shadows-psd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Curved shadows in Photoshop]

I agree with Lèse that there would also appear to be a slight outer glow or secondary shadow applied to the frame in your posted image.

Comment: Doesn't really make the world of difference, but what I would do in this case with the wrap is just click and drag from the middle between the 2 inner dots at the bottom and drag upwards.

Comment: If you just expanded it sideways and lowered it slightly when you warped it, it'd look the same as the OP's image.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from that image, but looking at [the original PDF](http://www.slideshare.net/geterrdone/steal-this-presentation-8581018), it looks like it's just 2 shadow layers (black layers set to multiply with a small amount of blur to it) that have been [transformed using warp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WS714a382cdf7d304e153d0941004907be29-7ff6a.html) to pull the 2 corners down.

One of the shadow layers is slightly wider, the other is narrower, but the bottom corners have been pulled down further. This gives it the effect of multiple light sources and causes the corners to look slightly more blurred than the center.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very video tutorial how to create this kind of shadow effect like a pro: http://methodandcraft.com/videos/layer-style-jailbreak

And you can get a PSD file over here: http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/content-box-shadows-psd, i recommend you to take a visit in the site because there are a lot of beautiful stuff over there